# How to test dpotrf

Tags: language-agnostic, matrix, linear-algebra, lapack

I am performing some tests in a scientific application. This application uses Lapack dpotrf Lapack function. I am not really aware about linear algebra. I must simulate a big call to dpotrf, then generate a random matrix to perform dpotrf on it.

Is this matrix must have a special pattern? Are I can just generate a simple NxN double matrix?

Answer (score 0):

from [dpotrf.f](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dpotrf.f), DPOTRF computes the Cholesky factorization of a real symmetric positive definite matrix A.

Therefore the input is expected to be a [positive-definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) and symmetric.

Also, dpotrf expects the input to be an array, i.e. your input is (N*N)x1. I usually reshape the output to NxN.